# Group By Creates Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using `Oracle` sql to create a sample data **GridView** and run into a very basic issue. So here it's, I've to organize data month-wise, say no of employees in a month based on a status column. So status = 0; Jan1 and status > 0; Jan2. I am not elaborating anything else as it has already a built-in view and that's what I've to use to make it work. So here is the query that I am using and the sample output that works fine except one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYEAR, DEPT_NAME,

--Month-wise data - Starts
DECODE ( upper((MONTHNAMESHORT)), 'JAN', NVL((FirstLetter), 0), NULL) "JAN1" ,  
DECODE ( upper((MONTHNAMESHORT)), 'JAN', NVL((SecondLetter), 0), NULL) "JAN2",
DECODE ( upper((MONTHNAMESHORT)), 'FEB', NVL((FirstLetter), 0), NULL) "FEB1" ,  
DECODE ( upper((MONTHNAMESHORT)), 'FEB', NVL((SecondLetter), 0), NULL) "FEB2"
--Month-wise data - Ends

FROM

--Sub-query - starts
(SELECT DISTINCT VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR, MONTHRANK.MONTHNAMESHORT,VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.DEPT_NAME,
  nvl(fnfirstletter(DEPT_NAME,upper(MONTHRANK.MONTHNAMESHORT),VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR),0) FirstLetter,
  nvl(fnSecondLetter(DEPT_NAME,upper(MONTHRANK.MONTHNAMESHORT),VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR),0) SecondLetter,MONTHRANK.RANK  
  FROM
MONTHRANK,VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2 where VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR = '2018' AND
  nvl(fnfirstletter(DEPT_NAME,upper(MONTHRANK.MONTHNAMESHORT),VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR), 0) <> 0 AND
  nvl(fnSecondLetter(DEPT_NAME,upper(MONTHRANK.MONTHNAMESHORT),VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2.SYEAR), 0) <> 0
order by DEPT_NAME, rank) q
--Sub-query - Ends

GROUP BY SYEAR, (MONTHNAMESHORT), DEPT_NAME; --Issue here - For the month-wise group by
```

**Output**

```
Year    Dept    Jan1 Jan2 Feb1 Feb2
2018    UNIT-I3 93   87             
2018    UNIT-I5 62   66
2018    QA      0    0      
2018    UNIT-I5           87   66
```

Here for the `GROUP BY` (MONTHNAMESHORT) clause, it creates duplicate rows for the department and that specific year. Say when Unit-I5 has data for both the months, it creates separate rows though it should be in a single row.
Any way to overcome the issue keeping the same thing, just an alternate for the `GROUP BY`?

**Update 1**: Even tried this one, but didn't work

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Q.MONTHNAMESHORT = 'JAN' THEN Q.FirstLetter ELSE 0 END) "JAN1",
SUM(CASE WHEN Q.MONTHNAMESHORT = 'JAN' THEN Q.SecondLetter ELSE 0 END) "JAN2"
```

**N.B**: FirstLetter and SecondLetter are counted in the view.

Comment: Your information is incomplete. please include row data for MONTHRANK and VWWEBLETTERSTATUS2. and include fnfirstletter functionality as well

Comment: `GROUP BY ___` means "give me a result row per ___". So with your `GROUP BY` clause you say you want a result row per year-month-dept, but what you actually want is a row per year-dept (because for another month you don't want another row; you want the months in columns instead).

Comment: As you study Gordon's answer, if you want to read more about the technique (which is called "conditional aggregation"), it may help you to know that the type of operation you need in your problem is called **pivoting**. Use Google to research the concept - in particular, you will find that, in addition to conditional aggregation, since Oracle 11 there is also the `PIVOT` operator (but you tagged your question "Oracle10g" - if that is your version, you don't have `PIVOT` yet).

Comment: On a sidenote: 1. Comma-separated joins shouldn't be used anymore. Oracle was late to support proper ANSI joins, but does so since version 9i. Use these instead (e.g. `from a join b on a.x = b.y`). 2. `ORDER BY` doesn't belong in subqueries.3. `DISTINCT` is very often a sign for a badly written query. Is the two function calls really all you want to join the tables on?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - **Generally** `ORDER BY` doesn't belong in subqueries. Sometimes it does.

Comment: @mathguy: That's true. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.

Your problem is that you are including `(MONTHNAMESHORT)` in the `GROUP BY`.

Your query is very difficult to decipher.  But it should look something like this:

```
SELECT SYEAR, DEPT_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN upper(MONTHNAMESHORT) = 'JAN' THEN FirstLetter END) as "JAN1" ,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN upper(MONTHNAMESHORT) = 'JAN' THEN SecondLetter END) as "JAN2" ,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN upper(MONTHNAMESHORT) = 'FEB' THEN FirstLetter END) as "FEB1" ,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN upper(MONTHNAMESHORT) = 'FEB' THEN SecondLetter END) as "FEB2" 
FROM . . . 
GROUP BY SYEAR, DEPT_NAME;
```